# How Do I Add A New Wpf User Control To A Element Host In Winforms

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

How do I add a new wpf control into an element host. I successfully added two wpf controls I created into elementhost1 (usercontrol1) elementHost2 ( userControl2). Now any wpf user controls I add afterwards are not usable. I am getting the following error:

> Error setting value 'Project_Name.userControl3'to property 'Child'.
>   Details could not load type 'Project_Name.userControl3'from assembly
>   'Project_Name, version 1.0.0.0, culture = neutural, PublicKey Token =
>   null'.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Professional. Tried using Visual Studio 2013 but its failing to add a wpf user control to the element host at all. Would have used wpf but the problem is have a winforms project I have created already so I want to add wpf controls in it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you show the code that adds the controls to the element hosts?

Comment: i was doing this at design time. found out that visual studio needed the project to be closed and reopened. weird solution but worked in 2010 though. however 2013 still find it a way hard to add a wpf user control into winform element host control

Answer (score 0):

closed and opened the solution and it worked.